# How do I insert selected part of a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this following code to retrieve realtime data every 5 seconds from IB with ib_insync package

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from ib_insync.ticker import Ticker
from ib_insync import *
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)

    def SimpleFuture():
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "GXBT"
        contract.secType = "FUT"
        contract.exchange = "CFECRYPTO"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "201805"
        return contract

    def onBarUpdate(bars, hasNewBar):
        print(bars[-1])

ib.setCallback('barUpdate', onBarUpdate)
bars = ib.reqRealTimeBars(SimpleFuture(), 5, 'MIDPOINT', False)
ib.sleep(60)
ib.cancelRealTimeBars(bars)
ib.disconnect()
```

That gives me the following results:

```
RealTimeBar(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 24, 17, 8, 30, 
    tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), open=9360.0, high=9360.0, low=9360.0, 
    close=9360.0, volume=-1, wap=-1.0, count=-1)
```

My goal is to update a csv file with only those columns: **DateTime**, **Open**, **High**, **Low**, **Close**.

Before doing this with .to_csv I think I need to put the results in a DataFrame which I need help with.

Using `df= pd.DataFrame(bars[-1])` gives me this error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: can you please share the type(bars[-1]) and type(bars). It'll provide some help in sorting out an answer for you.

Comment: type(bars[-1]) gives <class 'ib_insync.objects.RealTimeBar'> and type(bars) gives <class 'ib_insync.objects.RealTimeBarList'>

Comment: would it be possible to iterate over `bars` access each element and convert it as a dict? Even better, since it's a class you can call the class.__dict__ method to get the values of the class as a dict and store them into a list.

Comment: Please read this module's docs to see how to retrieve values from such class objects to tuple/list/dict or other iterable for `DataFrame` call. I am sure there is a method/property. Do note: a pandas DataFrame is also a class object with methods to output its contents into python structures (tuple/list/dict).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://rawgit.com/erdewit/ib_insync/master/docs/html/readme.html), to convert bar data to dataframe:

```
# convert to pandas dataframe:
df = util.df(bars)
```